# Mixed language programming: Is it possible/practical to create a single exe file for a program/app that requires no additional files?

Tags: programming-languages

I am as you can probably tell new to programming.  Could some one explain to me the limitations of mixed (multi) language programming?  Why isn't it possible/easy to write a program mixing languages and then compile to a single exe?

Regards and TIA, Ian

Comment: This question can't be answered. It is much to broad in scope and is very subjective to boot. Please ask specific questions here.

Comment: OK, ignorance is bliss.   It seems to me much time is spent on this subject.  Wrappers, libraries, ffi, api , com, corba, dotnet, dlls, interfaces, language interop,...  there are many resources available... I'm just  trying to get a handle on programming technologies and probaly a bit of a free ride so to speak.  there are many languages, paradigms, libraries (why re-invent the wheel?).  I may not ever be a professional but I am interested and want to learn but want to be practical by making use of what is freely available..blah blah blah..

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? yes.

Is it easy? no.

Let me pick a few examples for you that are real-world deployments today:

1. Firefox.  It's fairly self contained and is coded in both C++ and javascript.  It has a built-in javascript interpreter so this works.  But note: it's certainly not light weight!
2. Perl and C.  It's actually possible to use a mix of perl and C code and have the whole thing wrapped into a self-contained binary using perl's Par::Packer module.  But the resulting binary contains a full perl exe with all the required modules that the script/program needs.  It's very cool, but again the complexity is high (though it's easy to generate and use) and certainly not light weight!
3. Qt.  The [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) library/toolkit is a C++ library that also contains a (fairly new) QML scripting language for the GUI, which is javascript based.  It actually allows you to build a completely self-contained application in a highly portable system (works on everything).

But none of these use 3 languages (ok, the perl one might actually be useable with multiple lanuages but i haven't tried it).

So it is possible?  Yes.  Of the three above, Qt is probably the best example of "truly functional" (and highly deployed).  But the resulting system is rarely simple and easy.  Most of the above come with development environments to help coders get started, as doing it from scratch without the tools would be very very difficult.

Comment: "Perl and C. It's actually possible to use a mix of perl and C code and have the whole thing wrapped into a self-contained binary using perl's Par::Packer module..."  A self-contained binary - a package.  That's essential what I mean I think.  B

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a compiler for your specific programming language. There's no super-compiler that could merge code from different programming languages. And for some programming languages, there is a runtime engine that has to run the code (JVM, .Net framework).